# how to use wp_insert_post with array to create multiple page?

Tags: wordpress, wp-insert-post

I want a way to create multiple pages at once without duplicating the function wp_insert_post
for exemple i have this array

```
$post_data =[
        [
        "post_title" => "england",
        "post_name" => "england-premier-league",
        'post_content' => "england content",
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 0 
        ],
        [
        "post_title" => "spain",
        "post_name" => "spain-primera-division",
        'post_content' => "spain content",
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 0 
        ],
        [
        "post_title" => "italian",
        "post_name" => "italian-league-serie-a",
        'post_content' => "italian content",
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => 0 
        ]
        ];
```

How can I do that please?

Comment: At which action do you want to create those posts?

Comment: I want to combine the code with a plugin I created

Comment: Okay but any specific action? like any button click or anything. Put your whole code related to this question

Comment: Add it to the page template for example

Comment: WordPress of course https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/